# Taking backup of Database in Oracle 10g Express edition

Tags: oracle10g, backup

I have tried a lot but have always failed to get the backup of the database in Oracle 10g Express Edition. We are 3 people working on a project and what I want is that once we update database in any of the Laptops, we can take its backup and hence copy the changes to other peoples laptops too. Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tell you several solution

1)it comes with your Oracle Package.
Go to Bin directory and Click on "RMAN".It is standard feature in Oracle for back up

2)In BIN folder you would also find IMPDP and EXPDP. using these two you can take up of
a)Individual tables
b)Schema
c)Whole database

depends on what you need

the path of bin in my system is:

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN

3)another solution is you can use "imp" and "exp" present in BIN to take back up

4)There is another way but that depends on your knowledge in SQL and Batch programming

However the concept behind it is:
a)Male a batch file using expdp command of oracle
b)create a directory using sql command and set the target area for taking back up
c)save the batch file
d)use WINDOWS SCHEDULER to schedule your routined back up

5)you can use Standard feature of oracle if you are using Enterprise Manager

Comment: if I am right, one cannot use expdp for database lower than 11g.

Answer (score 2):

A cold backup of Oracle is the easiest means to get a consistent copy.  You need all data, redo and control files.  Query the views dba_data_files, dba_temp_files, v$logfile and v$controlfile to find all files.

If all Oracle installs are the same, stop the Instance and copy the files to another laptop.  If each instance is set up with the file locations you should then be able to start the instance on another laptop with same name, etc.

Probably the easiest method to copy Oracle DB contents to an existing instance is export/import.  Export the source, drop all schemas in the target and then import.

Otherwise, read the fine manual.  Build a small instance with no real data and learn to do a successful backup/restore.

Comment: I would have preferred a better explanation.